# Titanium + AJAX and array

Tags: ajax, arrays, titanium, titanium-mobile

The question is in the title. I make a request with Titanium.Network.HTTPClient

assuming the result of the call is (ty var_dump) : array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "Foo" [1]=> string(3) "Bar" }

EDIT : here is the complete function.

```
var paramsrecepteur = "demande=recepteur";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    // si la réponse est ok
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("**************************************");
        var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info(results[0]);
        Ti.API.info("**************************************");
    },
    // si erreur . ou timeout !
    onerror : function(e) {
        alert("erreur recepteur");
    },
    timeout : 5000 // implique un probleme reseau
});
Ti.API.info("¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤");
Ti.API.info(url); // url is defined upper & is correct.
Ti.API.info("¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤");
client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.setRequestHeader("Content-length", paramsrecepteur.length);
client.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
client.open("POST", url, true);
client.send(paramsrecepteur);
```

EDIT 2 : be carefull that you send a JSON object, and not a php array as i do ...

Thinqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have the wrong variable names. The proper way to get any [of these is shown below](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-responseText):

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
        // Print anything you get back
        Ti.API.info(this.responseData); 
        Ti.API.info(this.responseXML); 
        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);

        // Parse your results
        var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info(results[0]); // Print first index of the array
    }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately , i try twice,  Ti.API.info(this.responseText) and Ti.API.info(this.getresponseText); they both return null.


the solution above make an error because results is null , the stack trace say : 
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at UI/viewparam.js:80: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null.

Comment: THen you are not getting anything back from the URL. Can you show the complete code of you httpclient. `Ti.API.info(this.getresponseText);` is NOT valid code fyi.

Comment: i read the doc again , getResponseText() shoudn't be use in this case, ty :).
i just edit the question with the full code i'm currently using generating the error.

Comment: was my bad about the array i receive, which wasn't encode in JSON.